Dynamically group rows in a dataframe where the sum of the every n rows is as close to a certain value (LOAD BALANCING PROBLEM)
I've been thinking of a way to dynamically balance or even out the distribution of values in a pandas column. To add more context, we are consuming an API call where the estimated maximum number of words (yes words) that it can process in a minute is 9000 +/- 200 and can only process exactly 10 rows at a time. We can not pass anything less or more than 10 rows at a time. Why they designed it this way is something that we dont have much info on.
Now I have a dataframe of arbitrary number of text and a column containing the number of words per row. I've made some rudimentary methods, but I know it's not optimal. I'm reaching out to the community on what could be an optimal way to dynamically group records in a data frame, so that every batch of 10 rows that will be sequentially sent to this API endpoint, will approximately be around 8800-9200 words or as close to 9000 words?
Per row contains text of varying word count, as low as 600 words, to as high as 2000?
Thank you in advance to those who'd be chiming in.

The description is useful for context, but your question is lacking a [mre] to demonstrate what you want exactly. Please provide it a code with input + matching expected output.
